# What are the main differences and similarities between Rousseau and Kant's moral philosophy?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, kant, justice, rousseau

Main differences and similarities between Rousseau and Kant, especially in the subjects of justice, morality and also how Rousseau influenced Kant.

Comment: I would really like to see some effort in trying to do your coursework yourself here.

Comment: I have finished 80% of it and now I'm uncertain if what I wrote makes any sense at all so I had to ask here.

Comment: No problem, just edit the question so that it contains the main ideas of your 80% and where you are uncertain or stuck so that we end up with a question that does not take the usual word count of assignments to be answered (which would be way too much for this format) and with answers that can actually address your problems and concerns.